# How to get the value of global static variables having same name in 2 separate files in C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to execute a program in C. While executing I'm getting the same value for global static variables(**static int data**) with the same name declared in 2 separate files **program1.c** and **program2.c** where the **main() function is in program1.c** The actual answer should be **apple = 2** and **orange = 3** but the **static int data** variable is getting overridden by **oranges_set(3)** function call. Could anyone please let me know what could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
program1.c
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "program2.c"

void apples_set(int value);
int apples_get();


static int data;

void oranges_set(int value)
{
    data = value;
}

int oranges_get()
{
    printf("Value of oranges = %d \n",data);
    return data;
}

int main(){

    apples_set(2);
    oranges_set(3);
    printf("Apple = %d and Orange = %d",apples_get(),oranges_get());
    return 0;
}
```

========================================================

program2.c

```
static int data;

void apples_set(int value)
{

    data = value;
}

int apples_get()
{
    printf("Value of apples = %d \n",data);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: "The actual answer should be apple = 2 and orange = 3". Can you please show the exact output you are getting instead?

Comment: Never mind. `#include "program2.c"` is the problem. You should not be including the C file into another C file. You should be linking them via the linker.

Comment: What build environment are you using? Remove that `#include "program2.c"`. If using gcc, the build command would then be: `gcc program1.c program2.c -o program`

Comment: @kaylum --  I'm using Codeblocks IDE. If I remove the #include "program2.c" then it gives linking error. and I'm getting apples = 3 and oranges = 3.

Comment: If you get a linking error it means you have not set up your project correctly. I don't know codeblocks so can't help you with that so you should ask a seperate question about that. The problem in this question is definetely the `#include` and that should be removed (in general, no C file should ever be included in another C file).

Comment: I already commented on that - it means your codeblocks project is not set up properly. You need to learn how to build and link multiple C files. Are you still in doubt that the `#include` is incorrect? I hope not as that is very wrong and should definetely be removed.

Comment: @kaylum Now I created a project in Codeblocks and moved those files inside the project it worked perfectly thanks kaylum !!. Earlier the files were not included inside the project I was trying to execute them in standalone mode.

Answer (score 4):

These are not separate files, because you include the one in the other. This is equivalent to copying the entire content of `program2.c` and pasting it place of the `#include "program2.c"` line in `program1.c`.

For this to work correctly, you need to compile the files as separate object files and then link those together.

Comment: Since I'm using Codeblocks ID, I tried compiling program1.c to object file but getting error while compiling program2.c to object file.

Comment: I think the correct terminology is that both files form *a single translation unit*.

Comment: @MayurB The reason for the compile error is that you need to include <stdio.h> there, too. Anywhere you use a function you need to declare it; stdio.h contains the declaration of printf, together with a lot of other stuff. (Oh, I see that you get a linking error. My guess is that you got a compilation error first and `apples_set()` was not compiled and could not be linked, and/or you need to set up your project correctly.)